# PCB Identification - Many relays, 2 LM2596s, and other power-related components

Tags: pcb, identification

I'm looking at a board lying around in my home and have no idea what it is, expect for the fact that it appears to be power-related. There's a transformer in the corner, many relays, 2 LM2596s, and a rack of 2N6039G transistors in the right corner.

Pics are below.

**Right click and select "View Image" to enlarge images.**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Those who enjoyed this question should check out "name that ware" on bunnie huang's blog: http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?cat=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously of Chinese origin. It appears to be some kind of sequence logic control board.

Perhaps a massage chair controller or something industrial.

Comment: Just curious, but how did you tell?

Comment: The words "EASEPAL" and "EC-589A" may be clues that a search engine can [decode](http://www.easepal.com.cn/en/product/detail.aspx?Product_ID=75) for you  ;)

Comment: Can you explain how the chinese origin is obvious?  Looking at just the board, I can't find anything that would indicate that.  Only googling the EASEPAL did it reveal china.  I'm just trying to hone my PCB identification skill, not questioning yours. Purely academic.

Comment: I'm guessing Spehro googled it and left us to find out how could he be so precise

Comment: @ShannonStrutz The relays are from two different Chinese manufacturers (Hong Fa and OEG), the PCB is made by a Chinese maker **not** in the Pearl River Delta area (Zhejiang province), the caps are no-name, the sticker looks Chinese, L2596 are common in China, the heat sinks look kind of crude etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is a massage chair controller by Xiamen Comfort Science & Technology Group Co.,  Following is a link to the LtdEC-570 Maintenance Service Manual.
https://www.manualslib.com/manual/986236/Easepal-Ec-570.html
Happy relaxing!